# How much data could I store on a Rubik's Cube?

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory

Google tells me that a standard 3x3x3 Rubik's Cube has 43,252,003,274,489,856,000 permutations. If I wanted to store data on that Rubik's Cube, how much could I store?

The only way I see to store data on a Rubik's Cube is to assign an integer to each permutation, then convert that integer into binary. It would take 66 bits to store an integer of that size, so the Cube could theoretically hold 65 bits of information by my calculations.

Is there any way to eke out more than 65 bits of storage from a Rubik's Cube?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a computer science question to me.  The part that *is* a CS question, you've already answered.  The answers I can come up with to what remains are non-CS answers, like "glue a USB pendrive to the Rubik's cube".  What makes you think there is a CS angle to this?

Comment: Where should I put it than?

Comment: I think there's some CS content to add to an answer. Seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: What's the most efficient coding-decoding scheme? That's a slightly more CS question. Note that some permutations may be isomorphic under rotation, so I wouldn't necessarily know which side is up if I got it in the mail, so you need an unambiguous encoding scheme.

Comment: You can store 65 bits of information therotically but i think the bottleneck of the problem is that you will spend too much time at reading information,which means going from one state to another, simply solving the cube for each iteration of info.

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen Because of the construction of the cube, the centre cube on each face is fixed. That means that you can't map permutations onto each other by reorienting the cube. If you received a cube in the mail, you could always orient it with, say, red at the top and white towards you and then read off the permutation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's a good point, I hadn't thought of that. In hindsight, that should be a pretty basic Rubik's cube insight... Nevertheless, it still leaves open the question of how to encode/decode information efficiently, which is probably also an easy question for somebody more acquainted with Rubik's cubes than me.

Answer (score 5):

If you consider the cube as living in a physical space, then you can get an extra factor of 24 from its orientation: assume it's sitting on a table and note the uppermost face (six options) and the face that's facing north (four more options). That gives you $\lfloor \log_2 (24\times 43\ 252\,...)\rfloor = 69\,\text{bits}$, and you could get even more by considering more fine-grained notions of orientation, at the risk of losing information by somebody jostling the cube.